# How to get selected records from list view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, list-view

I'm using a Lightning Aura component and `lightning:listView`.
I wanna get the selected record from `lightning:listView` when I select the record like below img.

Successfully I get the selected record Id by using formula hyperlink,
but it occurs page reload, and I don't wanna reload the page.
And it should be clicked two times(double clicks).. so I wanna know how to choose a record by only one click.

Anyone knows how to get the selected record when select in `lightning:listView`?

[image: List view Image]

Answer (score 3):

Try This :

`var tablecomp = component.find('WrapperTable');

 selectedRows = tablecomp.getSelectedRows();`

> Where WrapperTable is auraid of your Lightning List View

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanna try it. But, how to call Javascript method from component? Like which event should be used?

Comment: For that, I guess you'll need a button in your component to perform whatever action you need. The Button Click can be the event in that case.

Comment: I wasn't able to get `getSelectedRows()` to work at all. @AjinkyaPhadnis, can you provide the link to documentation where you found that?